# Assign connection string during login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm working on a web project which required a different connection string for each different user(as each user has thier own DB)

I have a master database which will store all the connection string required info(eg. servername,UID,pwd,port which is all hashed)

I'm looking for an approach to route the user to their own database during their login.

What I am doing now is having a login page to check user login credential, if its valid login, I will then query the DB and get the relevant information and substitude into the connection string. Then redirect the user to the default page which showing their own data.

The connection string will be stored in a Property(or maybe I should call it a variable?) which is accessible in global scope.

Everything work fine. I am just wondering if anyone here can give me a better suggestion/approach to point the user to their own DB which I cannot think of.
and I was thinking saving a connection string in global scope is not secured enough.

Picture goes here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B78LCS4c8t4fbUp6UTFXTi1ib2M/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could Store the connection information within a Session object. When user request a db connection retrieve that Session object, and only it will be available for that user's Session. Using this behavior avoids the global scope insecurity. And maybe enable some SSL security (https) to your site instead of only http

Comment: Hi @DigitalDNA, thanks for your reply, the site will definitely run on https. I wonder if I assign the CS into a Session object, will there be any performance issues? as the CS will be used in the whole cycle of application (concurrent user expect to be 200-300). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment chinz i used to store some information on session objects (a whole Customer class by example) in my company's web applications and it hasn't have any performance issues with applications with 1000+ users. In my case the performance issue is in queries performed against the DB, so i keep an eye to DB Health (Indexes needed, index fragmentation, Foreign keys, etc).

Answer (score 0):

let the the master database store the connection string then there is no problem to redirect the user to their own database. 
when user login we check the validation in master database if its ok then get the connection string for that particular user and add that connection string to web.config dynamically

Comment: but as per question there are different connection string as per different user so how those thing will be maintained?